# Reputation Overflow™ on activity page sidebar

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, reputation-history

Some of the sidebar links in your personal activity page have badges to indicate certain updates. Sometimes, they become too large and overflow the labels:

[image]

I can reproduce this on the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS Monterey (12.5).

It seems to be dependent on the longest entry in the leftmost column; on Stack Overflow for Teams, where the last entry is 'Votes and reactions' instead of just 'Votes', this bug will only happen once you reach reputation levels equivalent to Jon Skeet squared(?).

[image]

Comment: That's a little hard to replicate :D

Comment: Took me a couple of months, yes :)

Comment: [No repro for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D9Qo.png). What browser/OS/device?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard could be a macOS specific thing right now - I'm sure that once you hit +100k you'll see it too :P

Comment: @Glorfindel it's 10k in your screenshot so not sure what you mean?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I meant that with your Windows? device, **you**'d need to gain 100k to see the same problem. You can try to edit the HTML to see if that would be the case.

Comment: On Windows 11 desktop, using the same number, only the box shadow overlaps with the label: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn7EU.png

Comment: If you get suspended and have a lot of rep, you'll see a massive bubble for the loss at the beginning and then another one when it expires. @ShadowTheKidWizard Technically, it's easy to reproduce by violating site rules :)

Comment: That sounds like a good problem to have, with a gain of reputatio+10065.

Comment: [tag:status-check-your-profile-more-often]

Comment: [Reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKI8Y.png). :-D